# how to read multiple lines from client to server

Tags: java, networking, client-server

So i'm trying to send multiple lines of code everytime i type something in the client console. However when doing this it only prints the output of the client in the server once, what i would like to do is print the clients output in the server everytime after entering a line.

Client:

```
    try {
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream outputStream;
        
        System.out.println("Write something to client:");
        
        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            
            System.out.println("Write something to client:");
            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            
            
            String message = scanner.nextLine();
            
            outputStream.writeUTF(message);
        }
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("[ERROR] Unable to get streams from server");
    }
}
```

ClientThread:

```
    @Override
public void run() {
    
    try {
        
        DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        
        System.out.println(inputStream.readUTF());
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Server:
public Server() {

```
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("[SERVER] Server initialized successfully");
        // consider using!
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("[ERROR] Unable to launch server on port " + port);
    }

    while (true) {
        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("[ERROR] Unable to accept client request");
        }

        System.out.println("[SERVER] New user joined the chat: " + socket);

        groupCounter++;
        ClientThread client = new ClientThread("Client " + groupCounter, socket);

        Thread thread = new Thread(client);
        thread.start();

        groupClients.add(client);

        //System.out.println(groupCounter);

        
        
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it only prints the output of the client in the server once"? is it because the server closes the socket? can you show us how do you create the socket objects?

Comment: No server doesn't close it socket, but if i type something in the client console input it prints out in the server console only once. What i would like to do is for every line i print in the client console i would like to let it appear in the server console as well. I added some code to show how i handle socket objects

Comment: so then, is its because the client stops the execution? do you also use a while(true) in the Client class?

Comment: The while(true) loop didn't help in client but the scanner doesn't continuously write the outputstream it seems with the hasNext while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the server side, `serverSocket.accept()` stops the execution and waits for a client to connect to the server socket. That's why you only receive one message every time.

Add an infinite loop in the ClientThread to make sure it keeps on reading the client socket input.

```
try {
    while (true) {
        DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        System.out.println(inputStream.readUTF());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```